# Object.wait(0) waits forever

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I have below piece of code, where the wait time is calculated elsewhere.
In some of the situations the wait time value is 0. What I notice is that when the wait time is zero the thread seem to wait forever. I could not find anything specific to this case in the Javadoc. I could just add a check for this, but I just need to understand why this is happening and is it allowed to pass 0 wait time

```
synchronized (monitor) {
    try {
        monitor.wait(wait); // <-- sometime 0
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [Javadocs say](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait-long-):

> If timeout is zero, however, then real time is not taken into consideration and the thread simply waits until notified.

So specifying `wait(0)` means wait indefinitely.

Answer (score 6):

From [the Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait-long-):

> If `timeout` is zero, however, then real time is not taken into consideration and the thread simply waits until notified.

If your goal is to avoid waiting when your `wait` value is zero, you can add a condition:

```
if (wait > 0) {
    synchronized (monitor) {
        try {
            monitor.wait(wait);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.wait(0);
```

will simply make it wait forever. So you can embed your code inside an `if` condition,

```
if(wait>0)
{
//your code
}
```